# Javascript read from Google drive document or dropbox text file

Tags: javascript, dropbox, google-drive-api

I have a Javascript array of youtube videos.

```
var vids = ['aHMeS7VFRZ8', 'qyV5FDUfI34', 'QGjYJ_dnlQE', 'kcgs1UHifRA']
```

I want to let my friend edit it easyly and modify our web page. He could modify a google drive spreadsheet or document or some text file in dropbox.
Can Javascript read from an external file ? 
No PHP!

XMLHTTP

not easy .. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's pretty easy (using jQuery)
Have your friend put a .txt file onto his public dropbox folder with:

```
['aHMeS7VFRZ8', 'qyV5FDUfI34', 'QGjYJ_dnlQE', 'kcgs1UHifRA']
```

on your js file do the following:

```
$.get("http://public-dropbox-file-link", function(data) {

    // data will contain the .txt file contents
    // edit:
    var vids = eval(data); // and it will behave as a javascript array
})
```

Comment: @Ivan, I added something that wasn't obvious, check it out

Comment: Your code does not have closing parentheses, it was making me ... dizzy

Comment: Does not work yet, but i see, it's contacting dropbox, but does not work yet..Please see source of rrrrr.kissr.com/home_js_dropbox.htm , line 185

Comment: and you have to put the values in the .txt file inside  [ ] for it to work

Comment: this vids.random(vids.length) should be -> vids[Math.floor(Math.random() * vids.length)]

Comment: Random was working before.. could you paste the working copy of the whole HTML, please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2vgq5/1/ this is a working example of what you're trying to do - I hope this helps. Edit: while this may solve your particular problem, I'd suggest you take some time and learn how to write better code. http://www.codecademy.com is a good place to start. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has an example implementation here: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/guides/getting_started.md

In it, they walk you authentication and reading and writing the contents.